# How to get only latest result from /page_fans_country?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am using this query in facebook api

```
  nikhilglass/insights/page_fans_country?
```

But it gives me an array of results

```
 data": [
{
  "name": "page_fans_country",
  "period": "lifetime",
  "values": [
    {
      "value": {
        "BD": 1,
        "IN": 136,
        "SA": 1,
        "SY": 1
      },
      "end_time": "2017-02-06T08:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "BD": 1,
        "IN": 136,
        "SA": 1,
        "SY": 1
      },
      "end_time": "2017-02-07T08:00:00+0000"
    },
    {
      "value": {
        "BD": 1,
        "IN": 136,
        "SA": 1,
        "SY": 1
       ..
      ....

   pagination:next_result
```

But i just want to get the likes for current time , i don't need the previous count, so end_time should be current date and time . is their any parameter for query so that i an get only one result(latest)

help please

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#time

Comment: @CBroe Thanks again . lol

Answer (score 0):

```
response["data"][0]["values"][2]["value"]
```